# (Edited) Given a number limit write an PostgreSQL query that returns the last person's name whose value fits within that limit after summing

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to write a query that (given a table that looks like this), sums up everyone's value in the order they appear and returns the person's name who is one place before the person whose value exceeds the given number limit. If the number limit given was 500, bernard should be returned because 250 + 300 exceeds 500. If the number limit given is 1000 bob should be returned because 250 + 300 + 250 + 250 exceeds the 1000 number limit.

```
 id | name|  value
------------
1 | bernard | 250
2 | bernice | 300
3 | bob     | 250
4 | buddha  | 250
5 | cheesy  | 200
6 | dog     | 200
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question pre-supposes an ordering, so it can only be answered if a column includes the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum.  But, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column that specifies the ordering.  Let me assume it is called `id` for typing convenience.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(value) over (order by id) as running_sum
      from t
     ) t
where running_sum + value >= 1000 and running_sum < 1000;
```